# Sharing an application to another computer

Tags: c#, winforms

When you send an application to someone, using another computer, besides the application itself, do I have to send the Resources File too? And if I am using a DataBase do I have to send the Database.mdf file too? And what else would you have to send to make sure your application works on another computers?

Sorry if this question is a repeated one, but most of the others just ask for a single item, either the Resources or something else. But I would like to know about everything you have to send.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Alright Steve, thanks for your help, I will take everything you said in consideration. Have a nice day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on your approach. i think you have a software with database and... that you want to sell and make it owrk on other users device. you can make you app make a new database on first start. you can include database files if its local and add to user app directory and... it all depends on you packaging method and tool.

or maybe you want let someone continue the project. so you can give other developer a back up .bak format or export database files from sql server management studio and other developer can attach them to the other machine project

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer virtouso. Have a nice day !